# Inverting DC-DC converter input ripple issue

Tags: dc-dc-converter, converter, debugging

I'm trying to implement an inverting Cuk DC-DC converter on a 2 layers PCB, in order to generate a -3.3V rail from 3.3V, but the circuit affects greatly the input rail. The 2 rails are used to power 4 Op Amps. I'm using the [LTC1617](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/16171f.pdf) from Linear Technology and I copied the circuit from the datasheet, modifying the components values to fit my needs.
The schematic is the following:
[image: Converter schematic]

I simulated the circuit in LTSPice and everything seems to work.
I had to implement the design on a 2 layers board, and I followed the suggested PCB layout that can be found in [this](https://pdf.dzsc.com/88889/7054.pdf) application note:
[image: suggested layout]

my layout:

[image]

When I power the circuit, the output voltage is exaclty as in the simulations (stable -3.3V with 20mV ripple) but the 3.3V input gets greatly affected. The voltage supplied from a bench power supply becomes a large smoothed sawthoot wave, with a pk-pk value of 5V, mean value of 3.3V and frequency 10Hz.

Picture from the scope (sorry if it's not quite readable, but it's the only picture I took):
[image]

It seems to me that somehow the switching voltage at the SW pin node pass through the inductor and present itself at the input pin. I also can't explain the very low frequency. From the simulations the voltage on the SW pin reaches exactly the same voltage values as the ones that I find at the input:
[image: Simulation]

This is the first design I make with a DC-DC converter and I'm not really acquainted with DC-DC converter topologies so I'm not sure where to look for errors. I'd greatly appreciate suggestions on how to debug the circuit. Thanks a lot.

I'm also attaching a picture of the full schematic (the DAC is not soldered on the board):
[image: full schematic]

Comment: What happens if you add a larger capacitor (eg. 470uF) across the input? Exactly which bench power supply are you using?

Comment: Why does C11 go down to -3V3 right after the inductor, instead of to GND?

Comment: L1 and L2 may be close enough to be magnetically coupled. You may want to test that and add that to your simulation and see what it does.  K1 L1 L2 0.3 ?

Comment: How are you measuring it?

Comment: Is there a load on the output? I’m wondering (because it’s been too long) if when in DCM the cuk converter returns energy to the power supply. Many bench supplies will freak out if you try to put power into them - that might be what you’re seeing.

Comment: @BruceAbbott I'll try to add a larger capacitor and make an update. The power supply is the TTi EL302RT.

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD The 100pf across R1 is a feed forward capacitor used to decrease the output ripple and is mentioned in the datasheet at page 6 and 7. Also thanks for the suggestion, but I tried to simulate the circuit adding the magnetic coupling and I only get slightly higher voltage peaks at the sw pin, but no considerable effects on the input.

Comment: @winny You mean the input ripple? I just hooked up the scope, paying attention to not create a loop with the ground terminal, which I connected to the grounded mounting hole. The ripple is visible also without the scope, because of its very low frequency (10Hz) I can see the changing voltage value on the power supply display.

Comment: @Bryan So you mean that it could be a power supply issue? If yes how can one avoid such behaviour? I tried both with the circuit load (the op amps) and also an external load (4.7K ohm). With the 4.7K ohm I got larger ripple at the output but that's normal. Still the input remained the same

Comment: Good! The 10 Hz part is really odd.

Comment: Do you have a current limit on? The 10 Hz to me looks like the circuit is trying to start up, but quickly running out of energy.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Ćuk converters, and this is definitely not the reason for your problems, but don't the inductors of a Ćuk converter have to be coupled? It looks like you just have two separate inductors here. (incidentally, [here's](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1611f.pdf) a much nicer version of that datasheet, straight from the manufacturer (Analog bought LT some time ago) without all those third-party watermarks and links.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is providing the 3.3V source?

I'm suspicious you are triggering a constant current limit in that supply. So when the -3V3 is operating it is drawing just a little too much current on the +3V3, hence the slow drop in voltage. When it drops to about 1V, the LT1617 shuts down and stop drawing current and voltage shoots quickly back up to 3.3V, the LT1617 powers up and process repeats.

If this is the case, adding capacitance wont stop the problem but it will slow the oscillation down. The current limit would need to be increased.

Comment: This is actually a very good point. I will try to repeat the test and check the power supply's current limit. Will make an update with the result.

Comment: Your intuition was right. The current limit was ok but the PS channel I was using turned to be not working properly. Changing the channel solved the issue